# Do not report skipped tests with karma-jasmine-html-reporter

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

Is there a way to prevent [`karma-jasmine-html-reporter`](https://github.com/dfederm/karma-jasmine-html-reporter) aka `kjhtml` from reporting skipped/pending tests?

I run some tests using `fit` and `fdescribe` and I want to only see results for the selected tests, however, the reporter is always displaying all tests from the suite.

Comment: dd you ever find a solution for this?!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, yes, there's a way to that with Jasmine (starting from v3.3.0). I've been able to do that in an Angular project. In the `test.ts` I've put something like:

```
jasmine.getEnv().configure({ hideDisabled: true });
```

Official documentation here: https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/Configuration.html.

Comment: Not hiding non fit nor non fdescribe cases.

Comment: Where would I add this? I have a `karma.conf.js`, but obviously adding `hideDisabled` on root there wouldn't do it as that will be picked up by Karma, and not jasmine reporter.